# Drupal: display views page instead of default node/%

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

Case is that im using views for displaying each of content-types.

eg. q=?news/12 for news by nid
    q=?product/13 for products by nid

Problem is when im creating (or editing) new content, it automatically displays (or refer) ?node/14 instead of ?product/14. Also menu link is created under node/14 link.

How could i set each view to referring content type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a view (display mode : page) for each content type, which displays datas from your node (fields or whatever you need). To do so, add a contextual filter in your view, on content `nid`, give default value : `content nid from URL`. Then give to this view a URL like `/news/%`. So `/news/12` hits this view and grabs data from news content type with id 12. Then you can manually modify menu link, or use [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to specify `/news/[node:nid]` as a pattern for all your news nodes (I never tried all this stuff together but it should work).

### Other solution

https://www.drupal.org/project/contemplate (seems deprecated...)

### Other solution

Create a dedicated template file for your content type nodes : `node--news.tpl.php`, but no more views...

### Other solution

Create a view displaying one particular node data (like I explained first, with a contextual filter), this view creates a block (display mode : `block`), you assign this block to a region (with block interface), and set this block to be displayed only for the news content type (last menu on the left on the block configuration page). Then with [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) you hide everything for this content type on the `Full content` display. So on each node page which refers to a `news` node, you have nothing in your page but your block (and the node title, which you can remove with Display Suite Extras I guess).

Good luck with it

Comment: Tried last solution. Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Huh, i tried with one contentType where url was /node/%. But its not working with multiple types. So i set the path of views to /node/%/products or views. I tried last solution but it didnt worked. I set the Exposed form to block to yes, and assigned that block to a region in block interface. But is seems like its not displaying any of assigned blocks.

Comment: You can also try the "block region" option in Display Suite extras, it allows you to define a field wrapper in display suite, which will be rendered as a block, available in the block interface : https://www.drupal.org/node/1795354. I worked with it recently, it can be very usefull (and simple)